# Create a custom render Appender button to add Inner Blocks

Tags: block-editor

The documentation for InnerBlock has a prop [renderAppender](https://github.com/WordPress/gutenberg/tree/master/packages/block-editor/src/components/inner-blocks#example-usage) which can be used to add a custom button. In the example:

```
// Fully custom
<InnerBlocks
    renderAppender={ () => (
        <button className="bespoke-appender" type="button">Some Special Appender</button>
    ) }
/>
```

the custom button does nothing on click. How can open the Block Picker Menu on click of the custom button?

Comment: Your button doesn't have a click handler which may look something like `onClick={ ( event ) => console.log( event ) }` - just call the appropriate function or whatever is needed on click.

Comment: @SallyCJ yes I'm aware of that. Do you know which function needs to be called?
I couldn't find it in the documentation as well as the source code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So I'm answering the following: **How to open the *block picker menu* via a *custom button*.** I.e. Without using `InnerBlocks.ButtonBlockAppender`. :)

> How can I open the Block Picker Menu on click of the custom button?

There's no (as of writing) "standard" function (like `alert()`) that you can simply call which then opens the *block picker menu*; however, you can wrap your button in a [`Inserter` component](https://github.com/WordPress/gutenberg/blob/master/packages/block-editor/src/components/inserter/index.js) (`wp.blockEditor.Inserter`) and call it's `onToggle` method/function on clicking your button.

Here's a simplified example based on [`ButtonBlockAppender`](https://github.com/WordPress/gutenberg/blob/v8.2.1/packages/block-editor/src/components/button-block-appender/index.js) (the *base component* that's used by `InnerBlocks.ButtonBlockAppender`) for the Gutenberg *plugin* version 8.2.1.

```js
// WordPress dependencies.
import { Inserter, InnerBlocks } from '@wordpress/block-editor';
import { IconButton } from '@wordpress/components';
import { registerBlockType } from '@wordpress/blocks';

function MyButtonBlockAppender( { rootClientId } ) {
    return (
        <Inserter
            rootClientId={ rootClientId }
            renderToggle={ ( { onToggle, disabled } ) => (
                <IconButton
                    className="my-button-block-appender"
                    onClick={ onToggle }
                    disabled={ disabled }
                    label="Add a Block"
                    icon="plus"
                />
            ) }
            isAppender
        />
    );
}

registerBlockType( 'my-plugin/my-block', {
    title: 'My Block',
    category: 'common',

    edit( { className, clientId } ) {
        return (
            <div className={ className }>
                Click the button to add your 1st image/paragraph.
                <InnerBlocks
                    allowedBlocks={ [ 'core/image', 'core/paragraph' ] }
                    renderAppender={ () => (
                        <MyButtonBlockAppender rootClientId={ clientId } />
                    ) }
                />
            </div>
        );
    },

    save() {
        return (
            <div>
                <InnerBlocks.Content />
            </div>
        );
    },
} );
```

So as I said, that's a simplified example. You can just copy the original `ButtonBlockAppender` component and modify it to tailor your requirements.

Happy coding!

Answer (score 5):

Custom `renderAppenders` require that you create all of the functionality of inserting blocks yourself. This is one I created a little while ago to only allow a single block to be inserted, you could modify the code as needed for your purposes.

```
/**
 * WordPress Imports
 */
const { createBlock } = wp.blocks;
const { Button } = wp.components;
const { withSelect, withDispatch } = wp.data;
const { compose } = wp.compose;
const { __ } = wp.i18n;


/**
 * Custom Appender meant to be used when there is only one type of block that can be inserted to an InnerBlocks instance.
 *
 * @param buttonText
 * @param onClick
 * @param clientId
 * @param allowedBlock
 * @param innerBlocks
 * @param {Object} props
 */
const SingleBlockTypeAppender = ( { buttonText = __( 'Add Item' ), onClick, clientId, allowedBlock, innerBlocks, ...props } ) => {
    return(
        <Button onClick={ onClick } { ...props} >
            {buttonText}
        </Button>
    );
};


export default compose( [
    withSelect( ( select, ownProps ) => {
        return {
            innerBlocks: select( 'core/block-editor' ).getBlock( ownProps.clientId ).innerBlocks
        };
    } ),
    withDispatch( ( dispatch, ownProps ) => {
        return {
            onClick() {
                const newBlock = createBlock( ownProps.allowedBlock );
                dispatch( 'core/block-editor' ).insertBlock( newBlock, ownProps.innerBlocks.length, ownProps.clientId );
            }
        };
    } )
] )( SingleBlockTypeAppender );
```

You can then use it like this:

```
<InnerBlocks
    renderAppender={
        () =>
            <SingleBlockTypeAppender
                isDefault
                isLarge
                buttonText="Add Block"
                allowedBlock="block/slug"
                clientId={ this.props.clientId }
            />
    }
/>
```

Hope this helps!